# Distributed Programming Technology

Tags: c#, java, c++, distributed

I'm looking for a technology which is targeting on building distributed applications. My friend adviced me to use CORBA (Java & C++ combination) . But I have read it's sort of obsolete stuff. I'm planning to write rather simple distributed application. What solutions would you advice to use? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to distribute your code logic to multiple servers and have it managed as a single entity, I would recommend [CloudIQ Platform](http://www.appistry.com) from Appistry.  You can deploy Java, .NET and C/C++ code to the framework.  From an administrative point of view, the servers work and act as one.  When you submit a request for execution, the framework distributes the request to the best available worker, performing load balancing.  With this framework, you can have producer/consumer, scatter/gather, and other parallel types of jobs.

The framework also monitors the execution of jobs, so if there is any type of hardware failure, other machines will get allocated the jobs that were running on the failed server.

Answer (score 1):

CORBA is quite old. To choose a library or framework, the questions are: why do you want it to be distributed? (what's the goal? performance / parallelization? scalability? physical constraints on locations of parts of the system?) Which sort of nodes will be running the various parts? What languages would you rather use?

Comment: My goal is just to have some practics and obtaining knowledge. By ascending, C# then Java then c++.

Comment: I'm assuming you want a network-distributed application (not parallelized locally). First spend some time understanding basic networking concepts. Then if you want to start with C#, I'd recommend implementing a Web Service, and then an application that will call methods from that service. You can try to find tutorials on the subject, perhaps this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/myservice.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Recommend using ICE(Internet Communications Engine), ICE can support multiple operating system platform (Windows, Linux, Solars, Mac OS, iOS, Android...), multiple developing language (C++, Java, .NET, Python, Ruby, PHP), and it is simpler.

Comment: Thanks! I just have read about it. I think I will try using it

Answer (score 0):

You can use SOAP web services. I'm currently developing distributed testing system on Python & .NET using using SOAP and it is easy to write and deploy.

There are a lot of different SOAP server/client libraries for different languages and platforms.

Comment: But if i'm not aiming on web? Can I still use SOAP?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CORBA, and technologies like COM and DCOM are all pretty much obsolete... I am not sure exactly what you want to accomplish, but I would look towards .NET remoting to build distributed applications. If your application is really simple, you can even use mailslots or named pipes to pass simple data across a network.

Comment: but If I use c# application won't work on non-Windows OS on other machine. Wouldn't it be hard to use some cross-platform solution? Anyway there are many Windows around, so thank for your advice. I have wrote simple piped application in c#.

Comment: Correct... you could run into compatibility issues using remoting. So remoting is not the way to go for cross platform solutions - I think web services is a great solution (easy to use and even more distributable than remoting). However, remoting performs better than web services since it can be used over TCP/IP. Here is a good article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978420.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As sinelaw mentioned, there are many questions before a good suggestion can be made, but, you may want to look at REST (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) as a way to transfer data between applications.  REST is nice in that what it can accept and return are flexible, for example, you can upload a file and return a PDF.  Though it is used on http, that isn't the only allowed protocol.  It is language/platform agnostic.

If you want to go with something that is standardized then SOAP or REST is probably your best bet, if you want to be platform-independent. If you don't mind being restricted to Java/JVM or .NET then there are other options, but that becomes very restricting.

What type of data is being passed?  How critical is security?  What platforms/languages should be usable?  What is the purpose of the program, the goal?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a portable solution that can also be used with different protocols, WCF on Mono might be a good fit

Answer (score 0):

For .Net I suggest you WCF , it's quite simple to implement and very flexible, and about CORBA it's a good choice if your goal is to understand deeply  distributed applications, but it's not more recommended for real projects, currently is very difficult to find developers mastering CORBA.